# No visible @interface for `NSJSONSerialization`... using iOS >= 5.0?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to use NSJSONSerialization.

The Base SDK is "Latest iOS (iOS 6.1)".

Deployment Target is set to 6.1.

I've got `#import <Foundation/NSJSONSerialization.h>` in the class using it.

But I still get a `No visible @interface for 'NSJSONSerialization' declares the selector 'dataWithJSONObject:options:error:'`.

What did I miss?

Here's the code:

```
NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSError* error;
NSJSONSerialization* ser = [[NSJSONSerialization* alloc] init];

[ser dataWithJSONObject:arr options:nil error:error];
```

Comment: Share the code causing the compiler error.

Comment: None of the methods on NSJSONSerialization are instance methods. Don't instantiate it, just call it like `[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:nil error:&error];`

Comment: Doh that's the answer. Still not used to noticing +/- when scanning the objective-c docs. Write it up and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataWithJSONObject` is a class method, not an instance method, so all you would do is call `[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:nil error:error];`

Check the Docs for it:  [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)